# How to use deserialized object on navigation to another page?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, json-deserialization

So basically I have a button. when I click it, two things must occur.

1) a web request to get the data

2) navigate to the other page and populate the data

the problem is that when the app navigates to page2, App.mydirectories gives a nullreferenceException...

How can I make sure App.mydirectories isn't null and wait before populating data to the new page.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            makeEventwebRequest(number.Text,date.Text);


            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        public void makeEventwebRequest(string numb, string date)
        {

            string requesturi = string.Format(baseUri, numb, date);
            try
            {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();


                client.DownloadStringCompleted +=
                new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(directories_DownloadStringCallback);

                client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(requesturi));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }

        }
        private void directories_DownloadStringCallback(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {


                    App.mydirectories = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<directoriescs>(e.Result);



        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because your code to do the WebRequest is async. When you navigate to `page2.xaml` your data isn't downloaded yet.

This is an example on how you could do your code:

```
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await makeEventwebRequest(number.Text,date.Text);
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    public async void makeEventwebRequest(string numb, string date)
    {
        string requesturi = string.Format(baseUri, numb, date);
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requesturi );
        var result = await GetHttpResponse(request);
        App.mydirectories = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<directoriescs>(result);
    }

    // Method helper to Http async request
    public static async Task<String> GetHttpResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        String received = null;

        try
        {
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null)))
            {
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {

                        received = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        return received;
    }
```

You should read an article on async/await methods like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx so you can better understand what is different from your code to mine.

The baseline is that you navigated to page2 while the webrequest was still being made, while in the code I posted above, the execution waits for the web request to complete and then navigates to page2.

Comment: `makeEventWebRequest` would need to be async as well.